# Getting DataVirt to Run when Instance is Started

Tags: jboss, data-virtualization, redhat-datavirt

DataVirt runs as it should when I execute standalone.sh in the DataVirt instance.  Is there a way to fire it off automatically when the instance is started, so that executing standalone.sh will not be required?  I believe there is a way to do this, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Search for how to run WildFly as service like in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272255 depending upon your OS.